# Only auto-shutown if PC is not working/training AI

Tags: suspend, power-management, shutdown

Is there a way to configure auto shutdown only when the PC is not doing any work (inactive and not training)? I am using TensorFlow. The system should shut down when it is neither training nor being used by me.

I am asking cause when I am training an AI, this takes its time and Ubuntu thinks the PC is inactive.

This is on Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS.

Comment: Not the downvoter, but best to specify what you mean by "not working at all".

Comment: welcome to askUbuntu... please let us know what version of Ubuntu you are using and which AI suite you are running. thanks!

Comment: I am using tensorflow and but not "working at all" I mean not training or being used by me.

Comment: Your Ubuntu system should remain on until you shut it off. "Auto-shutdown" is not enabled in a default install of Ubuntu. Perhaps you mean sleep? Or some kind of daily reboot for other purposes? Or something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write a cron job that checks whether there's a process of yours running (`pgrep -u $YOUR_LOGIN_HERE`) every five minutes and then calls `suspend` or such.

You'll need to log out though for this to work.